# Wachowski trademarks?

Tags: film-techniques, production, the-wachowskis

We all know the Wachowskis perfected the now famous [*Bullet Time*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_time) in the movie *The Matrix*. We also know they are on the cusp with the technology they utilize. **Are there any production/filming techniques we can attribute directly to them?** Please note if you will which movie they occur in.

Comment: Convoluted plots?

Comment: Stars doing their own stunts?

Comment: A propensity for close-up shots of tile floors and elevators?